# facebook Preview Dialog (for permissions) does not match actual access request dialog

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth

I have written a web app/site that uses facebook login. I have set it up so it requests "User & Friend Permission" = "email". But when I log in with a trial account I am not asked for permission to give access to email (and thus the info is not provided).

I need to get access to the users email address since I validate them in my database as well.

I am using VS2012 and the built in openid/oath functionality.

-Markus

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12969127/facebook-permission-dialog-doesnt-show-all-the-required-permission/12969471#12969471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not look like the facebook client in VS2012 supports this. I will have to write my own client.

see: http://forums.asp.net/t/1847724.aspx/1

Comment: See the very bottom of the above link. All one needs to do is update the oauth library.